# TYPO3: how to use nested globalVar constant conditions?

Tags: typo3, conditional-statements, constants, typoscript

Does anyone have any idea if it is possible to nest multiple LIT:X in TypoScript?

This is working:

```
[globalVar = LIT:1 = {$plugin.extension.constantX}]
    ...
[global]
```

This is **not** working:

```
[globalVar = LIT:1 = {$plugin.extension.constantX}] && [globalVar = LIT:1 = {$plugin.extension.constantY}]
    ...
[global]
```

I need a dependency of the `constantY` from `constantX`, because both should add different template paths. This means that `constantY` may only work if `constantX` is also set.

Answer (score -2):

What about this:

```
[globalVar = LIT:1 = {$plugin.extension.constantX} && {$plugin.extension.constantY}]
    ...
[global]
```

I did not try it, but this syntaxs works for a viewhelper, here is documentation on conditions: [Condition reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#globalvar) , [f:if viewhelper](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/If.html#complex-conditional-statements)

otherwise what about this directly in the typoscript:

```
if {
    value = {$plugin.extension.constantX}
    isTrue = 1
    isTrue.if {
        value = {$plugin.extension.constantY}
        isTrue = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: The Documentation says:
"The comma then acts as a logical disjunction, that means the whole condition evaluates to **true, whenever one or more** of its operands are true."

I tested it and it's not working.

Comment: you're right, I was a bit quick with the answer ... I'm checking if there is a syntax otherwise you need to resort to a custom condition ...

Comment: did you ever get this working ? ive got a similar issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57426653/typo3-typoscript-and-and-conditions-with-globalvar