# Typo3 TypoScript and AND Conditions with globalVar

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have the following typoscript,  I only want it execute when Language is 1 and page ID is 1432

```
 [globalVar = GP:L =1][globalVar = TSFE:id = 1432]

 lib.atoz = TEXT
 lib.atoz.value (some test )

[global]
```

However it seems to execute when the first condition is matched not both, it appears to be something to do with globalVar ?

**Solved**

```
 [globalVar = GP:L =1] AND [globalVar = TSFE:id = 1432]

 lib.atoz = TEXT
 lib.atoz.value (some test )

[global]
```

Comment: added an AND in at appears to work, thanks for your response though @empiric

Comment: `[globalVar = GP:L =1, TSFE:id = 1432]` will be true if one or more of the statements are true, so this won't fix the problem.

Comment: Right I missed that in the docs, sorry, @WelshKing you should post your solution as an answer for future visitors